# Bypassing SNS notifications in development for Elastic Transcoder

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, localhost, amazon-sns

I have an Elastic Transcoder job that sends out SNS Notifications to an endpoint in my app when the job has finished.  Obviously, it is non-trivial to be getting the SNS to be hitting endpoints on my local machine when in the development environment.  I can't quite work out how to overcome this.

When a video is uploaded it create a database row with the mezzanine url and some empty columns for transcoded urls.  It then creates an Elastic Transcoder job.

When the notification arrives at the endpoint from the job it adds the URLs of the transcoded files to the row of the database in which the url of the mezzanine file is located.  I know what these URLs will be but don't want to add them to the database until the job is complete (so I can serve placeholders if the database column is NULL, or if indeed it fails).

It feels wrong to check for the `ENV` in the controller and just add the URLs to the database immediately if we're in development, so I wondered if there was a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, your development environment should be completely separate from production's moving parts -- including SNS topics. If you duplicate your whole stack into a development tier ("dev db", "dev sqs", "dev rails") and regularly copy data over to it, you can isolate your changes' impact on production data while making assurances about behavior.

You could also then use a simple K/V pair in your Rails config (`environments.rb`) to tell it which environment to live in.